# Check whether two ip subnet in same network PHP

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, ip, subnet

I want to check whether two IP CIDR falls in the same network subnet.

e.g 192.168.1.10/24 and 192.168.10.130/24
Here I need to check both are in same subnet network.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It Works fine for IPV 4

```
function cidr_match($ip, $cidr)
    {
        list($subnet, $mask) = explode('/', $cidr);
    
        if ((ip2long($ip) & ~((1 << (32 - $mask)) - 1) ) == ip2long($subnet))
        { 
            return true;
        }
    
        return false;
    }
```

For IPV6
[IPV6 Package](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/http-foundation)

```
$ips = array('10.2.1.100', '10.2.1.101', '10.5.1.100', '1.2.3.4');

foreach($ips as $IP) {
    if (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\IpUtils::checkIp($IP, '10.2.0.0/16')) {
        print "you're in the 10.2 subnet\n";
    }
}
```